# How to process each item of List<> converted to a Flux sequence?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming

I have an interface. which specifies the data processing contract, depending on the type of exception that will be passed in the parameters.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FourParameterFunction<T, U, V, W, R> {

    R apply(T t, U u, V v, W w);
}
```

```java
public interface ResponseMapper
        extends FourParameterFunction
        <Throwable,
                        ServerHttpResponse,
                        ServerWebExchange,
                        HttpStatus,
                        Mono<Void>> {


}
```

Then I implemented this interface, for each of the exceptions:

```java
@Component
public class RuntimeExceptionMapper implements ResponseMapper {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> apply(
            Throwable throwable,
            ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse,
            ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange,
            HttpStatus httpstatus) {

        if (throwable instanceof RunTimeException) {
            serverHttpResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BadRequest);
            return someFunction(serverHttpResponse);
        }

        return Mono.empty();
    }

      Mono<Void> sumFunciton(ServerHttpResponse response){
       return response.writeWith(Mono.just(....));
     }

}
```

```java
@Component
public class AuthExceptionMapper implements ResponseMapper {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> apply(
            Throwable throwable,
            ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse,
            ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange,
            HttpStatus httpstatus) {

        if (throwable instanceof AuthTimeException) {
            serverHttpResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.BadRequest);
            return someFunction(serverHttpResponse);
        }

        return Mono.empty();
    }

      Mono<Void> sumFunciton(ServerHttpResponse response){
       return response.writeWith(Mono.just(....));
     }

}
```

After the spring application is initialized, I will get a list of implementations and want to process them (sort through all):

```java
....

 private final List<ResponseMapper> responseMappers;

....

public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable throwable){
 Flux<Mono<Void>> monoFlux = Flux.fromIterable(
                                            responseMappers

                                    ).map(
                                            responseMapper -> responseMapper.apply(
                                                    throwable,
                                                    serverHttpResponse,
                                                    exchange,
                                                    status

                                            )
                                    );



                                    return monoFlux.next()
                                            .switchIfEmpty(
                                                    Mono.just(
                                                            Objects.requireNonNull(
                                                                    someFuncDefaultResponse(
                                                                            exchange,
                                                                            throwable,
                                                                            serverHttpResponse,
                                                                            status)
                                                            )
                                                    )
                                            ).flatMap(
                                                    responsePrepared -> responsePrepared
                                            );
}

....

Mono<Void> someFuncDefaultResponse(.....){

return ...
}
```

The question is not whether such a design is good or bad (I am redesigning an existing application that is written on a reactive stack, but also uses an imperative style of writing code).

My task, when receiving an **Exception** function of some kind, is to run all **ResponseMappers** and their implementations of the apply method.

If a match is found, then execute the code inside the if block, if the provided exception type is not found in any of the **Mappers**, then throw Mono.empty and at the point of the call, handle such a case in the **switchIfEmpty**() operator, that is, return the default response.

The problem is that only one mapper is checked, the rest are not affected.

What can be fixed in this code ?

It is necessary that all mappers are called and if their conditions do not work, then perform the default action.

At the same time, if one of the mappers works, you do not need to sort through the rest.

Any idea what I missed?

Comment: As far as I know, every `Mono<Void>` is empty, because the only possible value for `Void` is `null`. I think you need to replace `Void` with something else, so a non-empty `Mono` can be returned. You can then use `Flux.fromIterable(...).flatMap(...)` to not get a `Flux<Mono<Void>>` but a `Flux<T>`, where `T` is the result of the exception mapping. You can then use `next()` to get a `Mono` with the result of the first non-empty `Mono`.

Comment: I can't redesign the code so deeply yet, I use what I have and try to remove the complex if-else assembly inside so that I can expand without changing the existing code. Therefore, I work with the fact that Mono<Void> is returned to me.

Comment: But still, won't every single `Mono<Void>` be empty? There would be no difference between the `Mono<Void>` returned by `response.writeWith` or the one returned by `Mono.empty()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I applied, the only drawback is that all mappers are checked, even if the 1st suitable one is found.

```java
return Flux.fromIterable(responseMappers).flatMap(
                                            responseMapper -> responseMapper.apply(
                                                    throwable,
                                                    serverHttpResponse,
                                                    exchange,
                                                    status

                                            )
                                    ).next()
                                            .switchIfEmpty(
                                                    Mono.just(
                                                            Objects.requireNonNull(
                                                                    someFuncDefaultResponse(
                                                                            exchange,
                                                                            throwable,
                                                                            serverHttpResponse,
                                                                            status)
                                                            )
                                                    )
                                            );
```